# Maze solver skips blocks Javasript

Tags: javascript, canvas, maze

I am trying to make a maze solver but it sometimes skips blocks. The code solves a maze from a 2d array. I think the skips happen every time a backtrack happens. In code `b` is a wall and `p` is an already visited block.

```
function solveMaze(maze, start, end){
    let here = start,
    path = [here]
    maze[here.y][here.x] = 'p'

    while(!(path[path.length-1].x == end.x && path[path.length-1].y == end.y)){
        let options = [{x: here.x + 1, y: here.y}, {x: here.x - 1, y: here.y}, {x: here.x, y: here.y + 1}, {x: here.x, y: here.y - 1}]
        let moves = []

        for(let i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
            if(typeof maze[options[i].y] !== 'undefined' && typeof maze[options[i].y][options[i].x] !== 'undefined' && maze[options[i].y][options[i].x] != 'b' && maze[options[i].y][options[i].x] != 'p'){
                moves.push(options[i])
            }
        }
        if(moves.length){
            let next = moves[Math.floor(Math.random()*moves.length)]

            maze[next.y][next.x] = 'p'

            path.push(here = next)
        }
        else{
            here = path.pop()
        }
    }
    return path
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wojak2121/k97dpbf5/10/)

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: Try placing `debugger` or `console.log(variable)` in different places to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is when you back up and try another path. So put the current spot back on the path stack.

This:

```
   maze[next.y][next.x] = 'p'

   path.push(here = next)
```

Becomes:

```
   maze[next.y][next.x] = 'p'
   path.push(here)  // put the current location back on there
   path.push(here = next)
```

Locations will be added to then path too many times, so if you are using the path to count then it won't be accurate but for drawing the red path, it's an ok hack.

Incidentally, if you need only uniques you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or try to change your push/pop logic.